# aws LAMP_Single_Instance stack create fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, lamp

Trying to create a simple LAMP stack on aws using AWS CloudFormation Sample Template LAMP_Single_Instance template.

On creating the stack, I get the following event - "Internal Failure. Rollback requested by user."

No clues provided on why this failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inspect the CloudFormation events tab on the management console (or with [describe-stack-events](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/describe-stack-events.html) on the CLI) and check what went wrong. In this single instance stack, probably CloudFormation was unable to create the instance, check the parameter values. For example, the key pair name should not have the ".pem" extension of the file, if that was supplied.

Comment: Unfortunately the CloudFormation Events tab provides no detail beyond the 'Internal Failure' message. I have not supplied key pairs, and there's no indication these are required or what format these should take if required.

Comment: Try launching the stack with the name of a keypair. You can list or create keypairs in the EC2 console.

Comment: thanks. I created a key pair in the EC2 console, and entered the key name in the stack template parameter field for 'KeyName'. That solved the problem.